# Cell format in Excel graph not synchronized when copy and pasted

Tags: excel, graph, format, label

I have data as two columns: first column as some names, and the second column their corresponding percentages. For example, first column as: `alpha`, `beta`, `segma` and second column: `10%`, `20%`, `70%`.

I made a bar chart out of it and on each bar it also shows the percentage level.

Then I copied and pasted this graph into another Excel file. Weird things happened. The percentages (shown as data labels) are shown in normal numbers (e.g. 23% as `0.23`).

However, the problem will disappear if the original Excel file is open. Once the original Excel file is closed the new graph will again show just in numbers.

I have checked that both graphs are updating if I change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you copy charts their referee stays in the older file which might cause trouble.
You can copy the whole sheet to the new file or you can choose the vertical axis or the lables of the chart and press format axis/lables.
on number segment, change the genreal to percentage with 0 decimal points.

Comment: hey thanks Balinti, it works!! but does it mean that for every graph i created i need to do this? That would be quite some work.

Comment: If you are doing this in rutine, then perhaps you should consider a macro for it.

Comment: You are welcome! if it helped you please accept the answer, otherwise, tell me what is missing.